# Как сохранить пропорции картинки? использую owl carousel

Tags: owl-carousel

В теге `img` картинки с размерами 900x900 отображаются нормально, но если 1200x900, то уже сужаются.

Что можно изменить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".owl-carousel").each(function(index, el) {
    var containerHeight = $(el).height();
    $(el).find("img").each(function(index, img) {
      var w = $(img).prop('naturalWidth');
      var h = $(img).prop('naturalHeight');
      $(img).css({
        'width': Math.round(containerHeight * w / h) + 'px',
        'height': containerHeight + 'px'
      });
    }),
    $(el).owlCarousel({
      autoWidth: true
    });
  });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yzLqv3qk/